# How to get Replication Factor of Kafka Topic from Java code

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have some topic name and i should to get info about it's replication factor from my Java application. I tried to do that with zookeeper library:

```
ZooKeeper zooKeeper = new ZooKeeper("localhost:22181", 10000, null);
String s = new String(zooKeeper.getData("/brokers/topics/" + KafkaTopicConfig.TOPIC_NAME, false, null));
```

But it has now info about replication factor, only info about current replicas count.
I tried to do that with kafka-client api:

```
TopicDescription topicDescriptionKafkaFuture = describeTopicsResult.values().get(KafkaTopicConfig.TOPIC_NAME).get();
```

But there is also no info about topic's replication factor. Is there anyway to get that info from Java Code?

Comment: [`AdminClient#describeTopics`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeTopics-java.util.Collection-)?

Comment: Yep, as i as i mentioned above, a have tried this, but there is no info about replication factor of topic(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. All the shell scripts are just Java (or Scala) code!

In the source code of `kafka-topics --describe --topic`, it looks at [`partitions(0).replicas`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/TopicCommand.scala#L286-L288)

Comment: Thank you for saving my time and efforts. :) this solution sounds good and equally effective to me.

Comment: Yep, sounds good for me too. I was confused with name method name "replicas.size" - thought it's current count of replicas, not replication factor.

Comment: The size of the replicas list is upper bounded by the replication factor

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the describeTopics, throug the TopicDescription you end up with a list of TopicPartitionInfo which contains the replicas information.